# JPA cascade merge on a child list is not considering columns modified in @PreUpdate or @Prepersit

Tags: java, jpa, merge, eclipselink, cascade

I have two entities A and B. A is parent of B, ie A is having a list of B as child.
The JPA classes corresponding look like below :

The first entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "refA", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<B> listOfB;
}
```

The second entity :

```
public class B {

    @JoinColumn(name = "A_REF")
    @ManyToOne
    private CoreRecord refA;

    private int updatedColumn;

    @PrePersist
        private void prePersit() {
        this.updatedColumn = 1;
    }

    @PreUpdate
    private void preUpdate() {
        this.updatedColumn = 2;
    }
}
```

My issue now is that when i first persit A whith a list of B, everything goes fine. Each object of B is cascadly persisted and the updatedColumn if filled correcty.

Then juste after persisting A, if i add a new instance of B in the listOfB and call merge on A, the new instance of B will be persisted in the database but the value of updatedColumn not filled correctly.

When i debug the code, i can notice that the prePersit method is being called but the modification done to my updatedColumn field is never persisted in the database. I have also notice that the preUpdate method is never called.

I would like the modification done in one of the method prePersit or preUpdate to the updatedColumn of the new instance of B to be persisted in the database when i call merge on A.

I've been tourning around searching what i'm doing wrong. Since then i have'nt found the problem nor the solution. I need your help please. Thanks in advance.

My JPA provider is eclipselink 2.5.2

Comment: Why do you think that PreUpdate should be called when you persist B? PreUpdate is called before executing the Update statement. But if you have a new B then it's doing an Insert.

Comment: Thanks @simon. I uderstand it perfectly. But the thing is that, i am not persisting the new instance of B directly, instead i call merge on A so that it would cascadly persit the new instance of B. And my issue is that, the PrePersist method is actual executed on the new instance of B, but the modificaion done on my filed updatedColumn is not strored in the database.